# Can a regular user find out processes of another user (regular or superuser)

Tags: permissions, process

Researching through posts, I noticed that any user can query system to find out processes that belong to others. Wondering, if it is possible to restrict this ability i.e. a user can only find out processes that belong to them. The same question applies to other resources if they are treated in a similar manner i.e. everyone can see how many CPUs/Memory is being used by other users.

Comment: Which distribution and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "find out" ? And what are you afraid should happen ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. But apart from which distro is being used, I am thinking about information isolation. Should every user be able to see every other users activities.